# active menu item highlight

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am trying to highlight my current menu item

```
<nav>
        <ul class="sf-menu">
          <li> <a href="" class="active">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Training</a></li>
          <li class="last"><a href="">contacts</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

jquery  code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(function(){
var url = window.location.href; 
// passes on every "a" tag 
$("#sf-menu a").each(function() {
        // checks if its the same on the address bar
    if(url == (this.href)) { 
        $(this).closest("li").addClass("first active");
    }
});});</script>
```

and my css script is

```
.sf-menu > li > a:hover, .sf-menu > li.sfHover > a, .sf-menu > li.active > a {
color: #FFFFFF;
background: url(../images/sf-menu-tail.jpg) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
box-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
cursor: pointer;
border-left:1px solid #434343;
border-top:1px solid #434343;
padding:6px 29px 10px 29px;
height:15px; }  

.sf-menu > li > ul > li.sfHover > a, .sf-menu li li a:hover, .sf-menu li li a.active {
background: url(../images/sf-menu-tail-1.png) no-repeat 0 0;
color: #FFFFFF;}

.sf-menu > li > li.sfHover > li > a, .sf-menu li li li a:hover, .sf-menu li li li a.active {
background: url(../images/sf-menu-tail-2.png) no-repeat 0 0;
color: #FFFFFF; }
```

so i need to high light current active menu item to display the active backgorund menu item with a background image . pls identify my mistake and rectify so that the menu will work

Need to add class (first active) to li

Comment: have you checked the values of `url` and `this.href` are same in some test cases.?

Comment: ok is there any other solution ? then without  checking the urls

Comment: `sf-menu` is a class and your treating it like an id in your jQuery slector.

Answer (score 0):

checking `window.location.href` may not be useful but if you really need, use this :

```
if(url.indexOf(this.href) !== -1) { 
    $(this).closest("li").addClass("first active");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To highlight current active menu item see below example

```
[DEMO][1]
  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/25amc/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var storedListItem = sessionStorage.getItem('selectedListItem');
    $("ul.nav > li > a:eq("+(storedListItem)+")").addClass("active");
    $("ul.nav > li").on("click",function(){
        var index = $(this).index('ul.nav > li');
        var selectedListItem = index;
        sessionStorage.setItem('selectedListItem', JSON.stringify(selectedListItem));
    });
```

When you click a list item in the menu the index of that list item is stored, it is then saved in session storage. One the page refreshes it is retrieved then the active class is added to that item index. Showing the page as active. It resolves the question because it adds the active class after the page is loaded thus actually showing it as active, the answers above would not do that